# How to update multiple times the same rows in one update (parallel arrays) from a sub select

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update

Here is the structure of the 2 tables:

This is the "main" table :

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE final_table (
    idx INTEGER,
    pids INTEGER[],
    stats INTEGER[]
)
INSERT INTO final_table
VALUES
    (2733111, '{43255890, 8653548}'::int[], '{4, 5}'::int[]),   
    (2733112, '{54387564}'::int[]         , '{6}'::int[]   ),   
    (2733113, '{}'::int[]                 , '{}'::int[]    )
```

This is the data from temp table :

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE aggreg (
    idx INTEGER,
    pid INTEGER,
    count INTEGER
)
VALUES
    (2733111, 21854997,  2),    
    (2733111, 21854923, 10),    
    (2733112, 12345689,  3),    
    (2733113, 98765348, 11),    
    (2733111, 43255890,  4),    
    (2733112, 54387564,  6);
```

The goal is to UPDATE the first table (final_table) with the data from the temporary table.

The difficulty lies in the fact that, in a classic update, the same line will be called several times and therefore will only have the last result in update. It is thus necessary to pass by a sub `SELECT` in the `FROM` of the `UPDATE` and it is there that I am stuck.

I can't seem to find the right syntax in the SELECT sub to do this.

Additionally, in the real table some rows may already contain data in the `pids` and `stats` columns. The purpose of this `UPDATE` is to add only the `pid` and their corresponding `count`.

The last query I tested (and didn't work) is the following:

```
UPDATE final_table AS ft
    SET
        stats = ag2.stats || (ag2.stats - ft.stats),
        pids = ag2.pids || (ag2.pids - ft.pids)
FROM (
    SELECT
        ag.idx,
        array_agg(ag.pid) AS pids,
        array_agg(ag."count") AS stats
    FROM
            aggreg AS ag
    INNER JOIN
            final_table AS ft
    ON
            ag.idx = ft.idx
    GROUP BY
            ag.idx
) AS ag2
WHERE
    ag2.idx = ft.idx
```

Also I use the `intarray` extension to do the `array - array` operation.

Based on the example tables, I expect the following result:

| idx | pids | stats |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2733111 | {43255890, 8653548, 21854997, 21854923} | {4, 5, 2, 10} |
| 2733112 | {54387564, 12345689} | {6, 3} |
| 2733113 | {98765348} | {11} |

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using a `JOIN` operation between the two tables and using it inside the UPDATE statement, you can craft your arrays from the "*aggreg*" table and use it within the `FROM ... WHERE ...` clauses of the UPDATE statement as follows.

In order to deal with existing elements inside the arrays, you should unnest your previous data first, merge it with your aggreg data, and update your "*final_table*" accordingly.

```
WITH full_data AS (
    SELECT * FROM aggreg
  
    UNION
  
    SELECT ft.idx,
           t.pids, 
           t.stats
    FROM final_table ft
    CROSS JOIN UNNEST(ft.pids, ft.stats) AS t(pids, stats)
), aggreg_data AS (
    SELECT idx, 
           ARRAY_AGG(pid ORDER BY pid)   AS pids, 
           ARRAY_AGG(count ORDER BY pid) AS counts
    FROM full_data
    GROUP BY idx
)
UPDATE final_table
SET pids = cte.pids,
    stats = cte.counts
FROM aggreg_data cte
WHERE final_table.idx = cte.idx;
```

**Output**:

| idx | pids | stats |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2733111 | [21854997,21854923,8653548,43255890] | [2,10,5,4] |
| 2733112 | [12345689,54387564] | [3,6] |
| 2733113 | [98765348] | [11] |

Check the demo [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/rcoDCxMEs1jGcL1Tzjo3ZQ/4).

Note: The `ORDER BY` clause inside the `ARRAY_AGG` function will ensure that correspondence between arrays is kept. If you need to have the exact original order, the query may become a little more complex and heavy, as that would require to involve a rowid (to be computed with `ROW_NUMBER`) and a further subquery.

Comment: Hello,
Thanks for you answer and for editing my question.
I will try with the cte, but, for details :
`pids` and `stats` are parallel array, `pids` may already contains some `pid` from the temp table, who need to be filtered by the operation `array - array`.
And to make this simple lol, `stats` is an array of no unique integer, so I have to find a way to reconstruct the array in the same order as the result of the `array - array` from `pids`.
Excuse me if I am not clear and explicit ^^'

Comment: Can you craft sample data and expected output that reflect a more complex (edge) case of your problem?

Comment: Sure.

`INSERT INTO final_table
VALUES
 (2733111, '{43255890, 8653548}'::int[], '{4, 5}'::int[]),
 (2733112, '{54387564}'::int[], '{6}'::int[]),
 (2733113, '{}'::int[], '{}'::int[])

INSERT INTO aggreg
VALUES
 (2733111, 21854997, 2),
 (2733111, 21854923, 10),
 (2733112, 12345689, 3),
 (2733113, 98765348, 11),
 (2733111, 43255890, 4),
 (2733112, 54387564, 6)

RESULTS:
(2733111, {43255890, 8653548, 21854997, 21854923}, {4, 5, 2, 10})
(2733112, {54387564, 12345689}, {6, 3})
(2733113, {98765348}, {11})`

Omg sorry I dont know how to format correctly on comments :/

Comment: So, I must keep the order of `stats` correct to match the good `pid` for the `pids` array. I can't make an `array - array` on `stats` because value arent unique and are in fact a lines count from an aggregation files.

Comment: Usually it's better to update the post, yet I've thought about it already. Maybe the updated answer can help you further, check it out.

Comment: Thank you !
It seems to work perfectly.
I will benchmark with the other proposed solution which also seems to work.
Thanks again! so many days on it ^^

Comment: Hello @lemon, 
Can I ask for your help one last time ? It's related to this thread's question.

Comment: Sure, go for it.

Comment: Thank you !
The query I am looking to do should update the corresponding values in the `stats` array if the `pid` is already present in the `pids` array.
So I need to access the index of the value in the `stats` array using the index of the `pid` of the `pids` array (via the `IDX` function for example). And then update to add the value from the table `aggreg`.

Comment: This query would be inefficient as already pointed in the "*Note*" part of my answer. If you think it's strictly needed to you, I can show you, although I wouldn't recommend going down that path. Also keeping correspondence in two different arrays, that don't hold correspondence naturally, is not a good design choice. One interesting option you could consider is to store your data inside a json field called "pids_and_stats", having key-value pairs like this (row1: "{21854997:2, 21854923:10, 8653548:5, 43255890:4}", row2: "{12345689:3, 54387564:6}", row3: "{98765348:11}").

Comment: A json naturally holds that correspondence, that's why it would be a good design choice. If you get smart at designing your schema, your queries will pay it back to you with good performance.

Comment: That's what I started to tell myself this morning. I'll think about that, however the order can be changed, just need each `pid` to match the correct index in `stats`. But indeed, parallel arrays may not be a good idea, unfortunetly, this is not to my responsability yet :/

Comment: Currently that correspondence is kept thanks to the `ORDER BY` clause inside the `ARRAY_AGG` function. Is this what you were looking for?

Comment: Well, yes, while the correspondence is kept, this is good. But I'm still looking for an update to add an value from aggreg.
I mean, if an `pid` is exist in `pids` from the final_table, I must add the bids value from aggreg to its correpondency in `stats` in the final_table. I even dont know if this is possible :/

Comment: Probably I forgot to paste your updated final_table records from this comments section to your post, I'll fix it right away. Anyways, this query *will* both add new pids-stats and update already existing pids to their stats value. How does the output differ from what your looking for?

Comment: This is different because if the `pid` already exists in `final_table`, its corresponding `stats` value must be added with that of `aggreg`.
Here is an example to better understand what I mean :
`final_table` row :
`(2733111, '{43255890, 8653548}', '{4, 5}')`
`aggreg` row :
`(2733111, 8653548, 8)`
`result`:
`(2733111, '{43255890, 8653548}', '{4, 13}')`

Comment: I think sums were never mentioned till now that I see it in this sample. If that's the case, you can't avoid a further aggregation before you generate arrays. See if this [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/rcoDCxMEs1jGcL1Tzjo3ZQ/3) works for you.

Comment: It works perfectly.
I had not thought that we could chain the cte like that.
I will still see to change the data structure for JSON ^^ I find that it would be easier to maintain and probably more efficient.
Thanks again ! I learned a lot today!

Comment: @lemon, it should be `ORDER BY pid)` instead of `ORDER BY idx` which does nothing since the subquery is grouped by idx.

Answer (score 0):

The following query (addressing the original question's requirements) adds only new `pids` and their associated `stats` from `aggreg` for `idx` values that are already in `final_table`:

```
UPDATE final_table t
  SET
    pids = t.pids || s.pids,
    stats = t.stats || s.stats
  FROM (SELECT a.idx,
               array_agg(a.pid) pids,
               array_agg(a.count) stats
          FROM aggreg a
          JOIN final_table f
            ON (a.idx = f.idx AND NOT ARRAY[a.pid] <@ f.pids)
         GROUP BY a.idx) s
  WHERE t.idx = s.idx;
```

The original question and subsequent comments don't mention what should be done with `idx` values in `aggreg` that don't exist in `final_table`. The following query assumes that new rows should be inserted for this case. The query depends on `final_table` having a unique index on `idx` to identify conflicts.

```
WITH pid_counts AS (
  SELECT f.idx, t.pid, t.count
    FROM (SELECT DISTINCT idx
            FROM aggreg) i
    JOIN final_table f ON i.idx = f.idx
    CROSS JOIN UNNEST(f.pids, f.stats) t(pid, count)
  UNION ALL
  SELECT idx, pid, count
    FROM aggreg
),
summed_counts AS (
  SELECT idx, pid, SUM(count) AS count
    FROM pid_counts
   GROUP BY idx, pid
),
stats AS (
  SELECT idx,
         ARRAY_AGG(pid ORDER BY pid) AS pids,
         ARRAY_AGG(count ORDER BY pid) AS stats
    FROM summed_counts
   GROUP BY idx
)
  INSERT INTO final_table(idx, pids, stats)
    SELECT idx, pids, stats
      FROM stats
  ON CONFLICT (idx) DO UPDATE
    SET pids = excluded.pids,
        stats = excluded.stats;
```

This query is fundamentally the same as lemon's except for the added ability to insert new rows and a join in `pid_counts` that restricts the rows selected from `final_table` to only those with matching `idx` values in `aggreg`.

Comment: Hello! 
Thank you, It works correctly ! I will bench it with the other solution by lemon.